# How to change the app associated to a protocol to one that doesn't appear in the available app list?

Tags: microsoft-word, file-association, openoffice, protocol

I want to change the app associated to the 'ms-word' protocol to Apache's OpenOffice (reasons for doing so can be found [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/msteams_tfe-msteams_file-msteams_suboth/opening-a-word-file-via-teams/fde6e697-2378-48f1-8d36-ed036dea05be)). However, when I go to the ***Choose default apps by protocol*** menu, and try to modify the 'ms-word' app association, The only options available are LibreOffice and Microsoft Word. Is there a way to change it to an app that doesn't appear in the options, like OpenOffice?

[image: Helpful Image]

Comment: Try to right-click the file, Open with, Choose another app, and navigate to the the OO `.exe`. Mark it as the default.

Comment: @harrymc I am trying to change the program associated with a certain protocol, not a file, so I don't think that your suggestion will work.

Comment: The protocol is the file's suffix, for example `.doc`. This method changes the handler program for opening `.doc` files (or whatever). The program must accept a file-path as its parameter, meaning being called like `\path\to\program.exe "\path\to\file"`.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't simply changed the default handler for the file types of common documents? Why are you specifically trying to change the protocol handler?

Comment: @music2myear The reason I was trying to change the protocol handler is because (as mentioned in my link) I was trying to open a Word file that had posted as a reference material for an assignment in MS Teams, and was unaware of the option to download the file. The desktop version of Teams opens .docx files with the program associated to the ms-word protocol, and so I was trying to change the associated program to Apache's OpenOffice. (Again, if you want to know more, click on the 'here' link)

Comment: Maybe you could refer to "[UrlAssociations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/default-programs#urlassociations)", go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Word Processing\Microsoft Word\Capabilities\URLAssociations` have a check.